# Exclude java.lang.* in Clojure namespace

Tags: java, clojure, namespaces

Is there a possibility to exclude the classnames from java.lang in a Clojure namespace?

I need to use variables like Byte and String, and here the java.lang classnames come into my way.

maybe something like (ns my-ns (:exclude java.lang)) ?

Comment: The clojure.core namespace depends on lots of stuff in java.lang.*, so I'm not sure it's a good idea to redefine those classes even if you can. For example, `str`, `keyword`, `for`, are functions and macros that use the `java.lang.String` class.

Comment: I think this shouldn't be a problem as long as these are not macros and use "String" at runtime. I can also exclude clojure.core functions that are used by other functions since they are internally fully qualified. So using String, when internally java.lang.String is used shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, _why_ do you need to name your variables `Byte` and `String`?

Comment: I am implementing [Shen](http://shenlanguage.org) in Clojure and in the core code of Shen Byte and String are used.

Comment: According to the shen website, it already runs on clojure? Perhaps looking at how it did this will answer your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use the fully qualified name, there's no ambiguity.  For example:

```
user=> (def user/Byte (java.lang.Byte/decode "0"))
#'user/Byte
```

After you've defined Byte in this way, Byte will resolve to your definition **without** the need to qualify the name

```
user=> Byte
0
```

Answer (score 4):

This is certainly possible if you manually remove the built-in mapping to java.lang.String before creating your own:

```
$ cake repl
repl-1=> (def String 1)
java.lang.Exception: Expecting var, but String is mapped to class java.lang.String (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
repl-1=> (ns-unmap *ns* 'String)
nil
repl-1=> (def String 1)
#'repl-1/String
repl-1=> String
1
```

I'll echo some of the other comments though, that defining something named String is not likely to make your life pleasant/convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the definitive answer to your question, but my educated guess is that you can't without modifying clojure itself. Here's my analysis:

The `String` symbol is interned in `clojure/lang/Namespace.java` as part of the default mappings (see the `Namespace` constructor in that class, which references `DEFAULT_MAPPINGS` in the `clojure/lang/RT.java` class). Interning means that there is a key in the member variable `mappings` of the Namespace class. The upshot of this is that *every* namespace starts with `String` mapped to `String.class` (see line 77 of RT.java in clojure 1.4.0).

In the `ns` macro, you can do something like:

```
(ns my-ns
    (:refer-clojure :exclude [<mapping to exclude>]))
```

but all that does is skip the code that interns new symbols (see line 3770 of clojure/core.clj in clojure 1.4.0), so it can't do anything to help you remove `String` from the namespace mappings.

Finally, if you attempt to redefine the mapping for `String` with something like a `(defn String ...)` the compiler will complain because `String.class` is not an instance of `Var`. See line 6797 of clojure/lang/Compiler.java in clojure 1.4.0 for details).