# Exclude java.lang.Process from namespace

Tags: clojure

I have a record named Process.

Executing the following

```
(ns foo)
(defrecord Process ...)
```

results in the error `Process already refers to: class java.lang.Process in namespace: foo`

also, I get the same error when I import `Process` into another namespace:

```
(ns bar
  (:import [foo Process]))
```

The following fragments solve my problem but do not feel clean.

```
(ns foo)
(ns-unmap *ns* 'Process)
(defrecord Process ...)

(ns bar
  (:import foo [.. ..]))
(ns-unmap *ns* 'Process)
(import [foo Process])
```

I would like to exclude `java.lang.Process` within the `ns` statement so that I do not need `ns-unmap` or a separate `import` expression.

Comment: [Exclude java.lang in clojure namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758279/exclude-java-lang-in-clojure-namespace) is closely related, even if not a proper duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It seems to be nearly the same question, but perhaps something has changed since it was asked 8 years ago?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your class using `gen-class` and import it as below.

Class

```
(ns tes
  (:gen-class
    :name tes.Process
    :constructors {[] [String]}))
```

Usage

```
(ns bar
  (:import [tes Process]))

(def process (Process .))
(prn :name process)
```